# Procfile commands was not found with dokku and node js

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, deployment, dokku

I'm trying to deploy my nuxt app with dokku but web:command was not found

i'm trying to run:

```
web: npm run start
```

but it gives me:

```
web:: command not found
```

Comment: upload procfile please and also try to run this web: which npm

Comment: @NaorTedgi i'm running this in PuTTy

Comment: @NaorTedgi like in this instruction https://nuxtjs.org/faq/dokku-deployment/

Comment: great see this : http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/methods/dockerfiles/#procfiles-and-multiple-processes you need to found where npm instaled on your machine like here under /bin that way i suggest you to edit your procfile and write only which npm

Comment: @NaorTedgi procfile is already in my node folder, i'm just need to edit it ?

Comment: @NaorTedgi i found, but there two files - Procfile and procfile ? which i should choose

Comment: yes edit that file

Comment: @NaorTedgi web: npm run start to this ?

Comment: probably the one all in lower case but show both of them and add the content to your post

Comment: @NaorTedgi git remote add dokku dokku@yourServer:my-nuxt-app
git push dokku master

but i don't upload my node_modules with git, i'm push it to server with sftp , to root folder and then create dokku project so git remote don't work for me what i can do ?

Comment: @NaorTedgi
  it gives me :
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: the first thing i was doing is test that npm and node properly installed on my machine connect with ssh to your remote machine and check if everything installed please check it run on your remote machine node - v && npm -v

Comment: @NaorTedgi yes it's installed

Comment: @NaorTedgi and i can run it local with command npm run dev or build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183795/discussion-between-naor-tedgi-and-albert-jovinskyi).

Comment: @NaorTedgi but i upload it wit sftp without git